# Identify component (diode?) based on photo

Tags: diodes, identification, components, surface-mount

I am currently fixing a Akai MPK Mini mk2 midi controller with a loose USB port.
In addition to the USB, it is missing one part labeled as D1. It can be seen in the attached picture circled in red. I think the text on the component reads 62S? Any idea on what component it could be? All help is appreciated!

[image: Akai MPK Mini PCB]

Comment: That's probably a set of clamp diodes to absorb transient overvoltage.  Since such are placed across the data lines and supply rails, the USB should work without it, provided that the connectivity and chip itself have not been damaged.   How did it go missing, bodged repair attempt?  See if you can identify connectivity of two of the pins to the USB data lines at the connector, and two others to power and ground.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll see if that does it. I actually bought mine second-hand, the image is something I found online. The previous owner probably lost/damaged the diode during their repair-attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE** Looking at more pictures, this is definitely incorrect, but left here in case anyone finds a similar component :)

My best guess (not totally convinced) is it's an [ST USBLC6-2SC6](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/usblc6-2.pdf) low capacitance ESD protection device.

[image]

Reasoning:

- Near the USB connector, so probably a transient protector (as *per* comments)
- Marking is almost correct (from datasheet, it should be `62SC6`, but it may be truncated)
- Pin 2 looks like it's connected to ground, pin 5 looks to be going (a long way!) to a decoupling cap.

My only doubt is the `D-` pins (3, 4) do not appear to be connected in that picture, but the vias may be hidden.

Comment: Thanks! That definitely looks like it could be the one. However, looking at the PCB, pins 3 and 4 indeed do not seem to be connected to anything. Pins 1 and 6 are going to the USB data pins and to the R22 and R18 resistors.

Comment: @Myreaux Yes, looking at the picture, with the vias they use I thought they might have squeezed them under. Do you have a picture of your "broken" board without that component?

Comment: As suggested in the comment by Chris Stratton in my first post, I managed to get the USB working without the ESD protector. Does this have any safety risks for the board as long as I make sure to always supply it from a computer USB port? Here is a photo of the board without the component: https://imgur.com/a/fbKiFy4. The previous owner left it quite nasty...

Comment: @Myreaux The risk is when you plug it in - there can be a lot of stored charge, and when it makes contact it discharges through the very thin oxide layer at your IC's input. The IC will have some protection built in too. Given the state of the board, I'd just be grateful it works at all at this point :) Many products will omit the ESD protection (they're surprisingly expensive components). My answer is definitely wrong, so don't use this part, but I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 1):

This component is definitely an USBLC6-2SC6. I did some soldering and was amazed that it worked!
Also I found out that pins in Type-B port often short to each other. I fixed it by carefully sliding the Type-B back lid up and having some tweezer work.
Respect to awjlogan and remember to solder dot to dot.
Hope I helped someone.