# My Akai MPK mini's PCB is not working due to a missing component, Please help

Tags: identification

[image]
I am a new person to all things electronics, I am more of a music guy so now that my Akai MPK mini is busted, I am having a rather hard time, so I would like to request a cheap and cost-effective way to fix my problem. I'm sorry if I don't know the proper terms and stuff.
I also have attached this picture with my board. The space should have a component.
My board when connected to the computer says "Device Driver not found", I have figured out that the board is not giving the computer the drivers probably because it cannot connect to it but I am not sure.

Comment: How did it get “busted”? Chips don’t typically leave the circuit boards on their own. What happened? We’re you trying to mod it? Show the screenshot of the error message. It sounds pretty normal - just install the driver and you should be set. Otherwise, your Windows install may be “busted” instead. Try on another computer.

Comment: Unless you tell us way more about what happened, I’d say don’t mess with what’s in the case. Software, USB cable, your PC etc. have to be eliminated as problems first.

Comment: The computer is missing the drivers, the board does not supply them.

Comment: If you're a new person to all things electronics, how did you decide to photograph that particular area of the circuit?

Comment: Did you buy this item used from the person who asked this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/502026/identify-component-diode-based-on-photo

Comment: Well I don't really know how the chip may have gotten removed, I just guess from the link Theodore sent, It was working fine for a while and then suddenly one day it stopped working, like with any computer, and any USB wire I use, thats why I guessed that its the board and not my PC,

Answer (score 2):

I doubt the missing component is a problem. It looks like that 6-pin device was supposed to be an ESD protection device. ESD means electrostatic discharge. You could remove it and the device would not stop working. It would just be a bit more sensitive to ESD on the USB connector.

You’ll have to tell us much more about the circumstances surrounding the problem you’re having. There may be nothing wrong with the device at all.

If there is some electrical damage to the USB circuits on that PCB, the L1 on the left of the photo could have failed and that would cause connectivity issues. Those coils do fail open sometimes. But that’s a wild guess and you won’t be able to fix it without some specialist tools.

Comment: Ah, alright, if you say so, I just guessed that the missing component may be the problem, hence I asked, if there is some other thing, then I don't know about that at all

Comment: How would you exactly identify what is the exact problem that is happening in the baord

Answer (score 0):

The component is missing but it does not cause problems. The USB data wires are still connected to PC. You are clearly able to connect it to your PC just fine because it says drivers are missing, otherwise it would say there is another problem.